# Using Swift Generics in Base class to easily return type class to subclass

Tags: swift, generics, viper-architecture

I want to hold onto a Interactor class in a BasePresenter class, but for the life of me I can't figure out how on earth to use generics easily in Swift. I want to have a function in the base class (like BasePresenter interactorForType).

```swift
public class InboxListPresenter: BasePresenter, ObservableObject {
        
    public init(interactor: InboxListInteractor) {
        
        super.init(router: InboxListRouter(viewData: viewData), interactor: interactor)
    }
    
    func findInboxNotifications() {
        
        interactorForType(type: InboxListInteractor.self).findInboxNotifications() { inboxNotifications, errorCode in
            
            // do something
        }
    }    
}
```

Here's the BasePresenter where I want to hold the generic object. I'm trying to use protocols (ILibertyInteractor)

```swift
open class BasePresenter {
    
    public let router:ILibertyRouter
    public let interactor:ILibertyInteractor
    
    public init(router:ILibertyRouter, interactor:ILibertyInteractor) {
        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
            
    func interactorForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return interactor as! T
    }
    
    func routerForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return router as! T
    }
}
```

The above interactorForType does a force unwrap on interaction that I want to avoid. Also, I don't really want to pass in the object either. I'd like to use protocols and generics to have a generic function that returns type T.

Below is the start of what I was trying to allow returning the type back within the presenter above.

```swift
public protocol ILibertyPresenter {
    var router:ILibertyRouter { get }
}

public protocol ILibertyRouter {
    
}

public protocol ILibertyInteractor {
//    associatedtype T
    
//    func trueInteractor() -> T
}
```

Comment: Does this do what you need? `func interactorForType() -> ILibertyInteractor { return interactor }`

Comment: You cannot change the return type of a method in a subclass in Swift (not even to make it more specialized). What you're trying to do here is not possible. Start by getting rid of the class inheritance (i.e. BasePresenter). Mixing class inheritance with generics and protocols makes a mess of types. Write a few concrete presenters, routers, and interactors. See where actual code duplication occurs. From that, extract protocols or generics (I often find in practice you need very few). Strongly avoid creating a type just to fill an architecture slot. Make sure it's doing work for you.

Comment: Your design seems contradictory. You are using protocols for everything, which means you don't know the concrete types being used, allowing for a kind of generic code because when you call methods on the protocol it is dynamically dispatched to the appropriate class. But on the flipside you want to use real generics, which depend on concrete type information so that the compiler can statically dispatch the methods.

Comment: The fact that you have a InboxListPresenter and a InboxListInteractor and a InboxListRouter is strongly suggestive that these types aren't pulling their weight and aren't providing any flexibility. If InboxListInteractor can't be used with anything except InboxListPresenter (or "Mock"InboxListPresenter) , then you're not actually writing generic code. You're writing very concrete code in a complicated way. Concrete code is fine (it's *great*!), but there's no reason it can't then just be simple.

Comment: Rob is right. Don't blend SubClassing with Protocols, you can do it all using protocols alone. InboxListPresenter still needs to be a class since it needs to be an ObserveableObject to work well with SwiftUI.

Comment: BTW, while it's focused on UIKit rather than SwiftUI (SwiftUI actually make a lot of these things harder to abstract IMO), I highly recommend Dave DeLong's "A Better MVC" talk to see how to think about these kinds of designs and how to implement them in Swift.  https://davedelong.com/blog/2017/11/06/a-better-mvc-part-1-the-problems/ and the talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWVzCd5FYbs

Comment: thanks for the open thoughts. I have a 10yr plus Java background and was trying to blend in some generics into the mix and store and just return the concrete class back to the caller without doing an as? or passing in self.  Yes, I'm using SwiftUI with it, so I'll have to keep it a class. My main point was trying to eliminate the duplicate coding of attributes in each subclass.  But I was trying to force some consistency using ILibertyPresenter on each presenter.  This is a subset of VIPER architecture.

Comment: Here's the pattern that I started off with.   https://www.raywenderlich.com/8440907-getting-started-with-the-viper-architecture-pattern

Answer (score 2):

There are two things here. There is the question you ask, "how to store a generic?", and then there is what your example code seems to be trying to do.

## How to store a generic value

The short answer for how to store a generic (assuming going through `Any` is undesirable - and it is undesirable), is to store it in a generic.

If want to hold on to a generic type as its explicit type, the thing holding onto it also have to be generic and specialized on the same type.  That would require your `InboxListPresenter` to be generic too.  So you could do this:

```swift
open class BasePresenter <InteractorType: IteractorProtocol>{
    
    public let router:ILibertyRouter
    public let interactor: InteractorType // You can do this now
    
    public init(router:ILibertyRouter, interactor:ILibertyInteractor) {
        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
            
    /* you don't need this now, because InteractorType is part of the generic class definition 
    func interactorForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return interactor as! T
    }
    */
    
    func routerForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return router as! T
    }
}
```

In this example, I specified that `IteractorType` conforms to `InteractorProtocol`.

Under some circumstances you eliminate the need for the surrounding type to be generic, allowing you to do this:

```swift
open class BasePresenter{
    
    public let router:ILibertyRouter
    public let interactor: InteractorProtocol
    
    public init(router:ILibertyRouter, interactor:InteractorProtocol) {
        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
            
    /* you don't need this now, because InteractorProtocol should define the interface for all Interactors 
    func interactorForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return interactor as! T
    }
    */
    
    func routerForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return router as! T
    }
}
```

Specifically you can do that *if* `InteractorProtocol` doesn't have, as the dreaded Swift compiler error will say, "Self or associated type constraints".   Basically if you have `where` clauses or other protocol conformance constraints on the protocol or on the associated types in the protocol, then you can only use the protocol to constrain generic parameters.

If you it doesn't have `Self` or associated type constraints, then you can use it as though it were an ordinary type, including as the type for a stored property.

## What the code seems to want

The code you've shown is basically a poster child for classic OOP-style inheritance.  That's not the only way to solve the problem, but looking at it, it screams for an `Interactor` base class that defines the interface, and for concrete implementations to do the actual work.   I don't know what `Interactor` has to do, but if it's sufficiently complex, you can apply all sorts of design patterns to avoid having to have a gazillion subclasses of it.  And you can borrow the idea from Cocoa/CocoaTouch of declaring delegate protocols so you can modify the behavior that way.

Anyway the inheritance approach is fairly straight forward.

```swift
open class Iteractor {
    // Just replace the closure parameter types with whatever they're supposed to be
    func findInboxNotifications((Any, ErrorCode) -> Void) { fatalError("Implement in subclass!") }
}
```

Then you use that as your base class for your concrete Interactor types.

```swift
final class AConcreteInteractor: Iteractor {
    override func findInboxNotifications ((Any, ErrorCode) -> Void)  {
        /* Do actual work here */ 
    }
}
```

Then in your `BasePresenter`:

```swift
open class BasePresenter {
    
    public let router:ILibertyRouter
    public let interactor: Iteractor
    
    public init(router:ILibertyRouter, interactor: Iteractor) {
        self.router = router
        self.interactor = interactor
    }
            
    /* This isn't needed because you'll use `interactor` polymorphically`
    func interactorForType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
        return interactor as! T
    }
    */

    ...
}
```

`InboxListPresenter` would then look like this

```swift
public class InboxListPresenter: BasePresenter, ObservableObject {
        
    public init(interactor: InboxListInteractor) {
        
        super.init(router: InboxListRouter(viewData: viewData), interactor: interactor)
    }
    
    func findInboxNotifications() {
        
        iteractor.findInboxNotifications() { inboxNotifications, errorCode in
            
            // do something
        }
    }    
}
```

### Using Protocols instead of Inheritance

I don't think protocols is a good fit in this case, but in some ways, protocols can substitute for class-based inheritance; but since you have to store the interactor, that puts you right back at having to make sure you don't have `Self` or associated type constraints.

When used this way the only advantage to protocols over inheritance is that you get some better compiler checks - for example, it can ensure that all required implementation methods are actually implemented by the types conforming to the protocol, whereas in class inheritance, the base class always defines them (because unlike Java, Swift doesn't let you define a purely abstract base class, nor does it allow you specify "pure" virtual methods likes C++).  You pay for that benefit in being more constrained how you define them so that you can use them as stored property types.

I would say that the code you present in your question *wants* to use class-based inheritance for your Interactors.  Unless you have some good reason not to, I would just go with that rather than try to force the square peg into a round hole.

Comment: Thank for the full suggestions! yeah, I'm struggling to find an easy solution when coming from a major Java +10yr background into Swift when it relates to generics. Plus not to mention having a pseudo force architecture with how SwiftUI apps are built out. I'll try these options out, but initially my thoughts are I'm outta luck to store the objects generically and natively return the subclass w/o doing some boilerplate code. I may just go the protocol route and provide consistency with each implemented concrete class and just have the extra attribute added to each.

Comment: LOL. I've struggled a ton even on generic's examples in Swift. But still haven't found a nice solution. I think you hit the nail on the head.. "Swift doesn't let you define a purely abstract base class".  That's where I'm missing a nice easy way to store things in an open class and just return the objects natively.

Comment: You can still define base classes, you just can't prevent them from being instantiated, and except for required initializers, you can't enforce that subclasses will override the methods they should.  But most of Cocoa/CocoaTouch is built like that and it works pretty well.  You can build a non-generic base class with the interface you want that doesn't depend on generics, and then define generic subclass of that base class.

Comment: So `class Base { }` and `class Subclass<T>: Base { }`.

Comment: You can sort of prevent a base class from being instantiated by making its initializer internal, but anything within in the module can still create one, and anyone outside of the module trying to call `super.init` in a subclass will have problems.  Private initializers are mainly useful for enforcing objects are created through factory methods.